# Can't run one particular program from Terminal without using its full path

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I want to run a program `ds9` from the Terminal. The program is clearly in the PATH, which I determined by running:

```
which ds9
/Users/evgenii/miniconda3/envs/iraf/bin/ds9
```

But when I run the command by typing`ds9`, it shows me the following error:

```
-bash: /Applications/ds9.app/Contents/MacOS/ds9: No such file or directory
```

I can still execute it fine if I use the full path as follows:

```
/Users/evgenii/miniconda3/envs/iraf/bin/ds9
```

What's going on? Why is it trying to run `/Applications/ds9.app`?

Permissions are as follows:

```
-rwxrwxr-x@ 1 evgenii  staff  18613852  9 Nov 20:13 /Users/evgenii/miniconda3/envs/iraf/bin/ds9
```

#### Update:

Here is the output of running `type -a ds9` command:

```
type -a ds9
ds9 is aliased to `/Applications/ds9.app/Contents/MacOS/ds9 -xpa no'
ds9 is /Users/evgenii/miniconda3/envs/iraf/bin/ds9
```

Comment: Don't use `which`. It's an external program, so it can't tell about shell aliases.

Comment: Receipe to work with commands: use `PATH` rather than `alias` and `type` rather than `which`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The command is apparently aliased to a broken alias. First, check for all the matches for `ds9` in `PATH` environment variable, by executing the following command:

`type -a ds9`

As per your updated question, it's apparent from the output of `type -a ds9` command, that an alias is shadowing the actual command.

To execute the actual command by ignoring the alias, and without specifying the full path, prepend a `\` (backslash) character before the command. This ignores any bash defined alias.

If you do not wish to prepend the backslash before the command every time, figure out where the alias is being created, and either remove it, or override the alias with the actual command.

Comment: The `ds9` alias definition is most probably in `~/.bashrc` and should be removed there (because it’s a bad method leading to this kind of problem). `grep ds9 ~/.bashrc` will confirm it.

Answer (score 4):

I see this was solved for the asker, but for future readers I want to mention that it could also be the case that the command was **hashed** and then the file removed.  (See `help hash` for info.)

`type -a commandname` will not show you that, only `type commandname` will.

In this case, `hash -d ds9` would be all that would be needed.